# Macro errors with member function

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm having fun with macros (not)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define DEF_ATTRIBUTE(type, name) type name;\
    typedef void (*type_name_t)(CLASS_NAME*);\
    type_name_t ptr_type_name;\
    void type_name(){( ptr_type_name = &CLASS_NAME::type_name);}\

class Test
{
    public:
        #define CLASS_NAME Test
        DEF_ATTRIBUTE(int, i_Test);

        void Print()
        {
            cout << "Test::Print()" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.Print();
}
```

Which expands to :

```
class Test
{
    public:

        int i_Test; typedef void (*type_name_t)(Test*); type_name_t ptr_type_name; void type_name(){( ptr_type_name = &Test::type_name);};

        void Print()
        {
            cout << "Test::Print()" << endl;
        }
};
```

And yields the compiler error :

> main.cpp: In member function void Test::type_name():
>       main.cpp:16: error: cannot convert void (Test::*)() to void (*)(Test*) in assignment

As far as I can understand, the function pointers are equivalent. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using macros in C++ ? Putting macros in the middle of code ?

Comment: Here we go again. If you don't like it, don't post. I'm not asking for an opinion, just an answer.

Comment: I think this is one of those square macros trying to fit into a round problem.

Comment: @nakiya: Although the answers here do indeed answer the question, the question itself is hinting at bigger issues, i.e. using brute force (macros) to solve a problem where there is a set of language features that will do what you want. Search using Google to learn why C preprocessor macros are an unfortunate evil. In C++, macros used like this are usually a code-smell!

Comment: @Skizz : Of course, there are trade offs. That is why people still use C++ in the first place. But then, this is also a trade off. If I could do what I want in any other 'elegant' way, I would have. :)

Comment: @Skizz : Find me a reflection mechanism for C++ that doesn't depend on macros and I'll agree.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : Unfortunately, I can't use boost here. Third party libraries are not allowed. But I'll look into Traits. Thanks.

Comment: @nakiya: It's hard to tell what your goal is with the sample shown. Since C++ does not support reflection, you must ask yourself if it is the right language to develop in. Other languages do support reflection (C# for example). But then, do you need a complete reflection system? Ultimately, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Skizz: I work with a messaging system. I want to unpack messages into structures. Something like this : I can get a field from a message by name , if an attribute exists by the same name in the struct passed, I want to unpack that field to the struct. Now, if I can make the linker export the function names my macro generates in the object files, I can use `nm` to find out the layout of a struct and so on... At least that was what I thought in my Eureka moment :(

Comment: @nakiya: If it were me, I'd have the first item in the message indicate the type of message, then have a factory to create instances of classes for that type. Then each class would have a deserialise method which decodes the rest of the message (like the << and >> operators). You'd also have a serialise method that did the reverse. I'm assuming the messages arrive via an external interface (like a TCP/IP socket).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function pointers aren't equivalent.

```
void (*type_name_t)(Test*)
```

is not the same as

```
&Test::type_name
```

Your function pointer is of type: a pointer to a function that takes one argument, a Test pointer, and returns no value.

What you want is a pointer-to-member-function, specifically, a pointer to a member function that takes no arguments and returns no value:

```
void (Test::*type_name_t) (); // note the empty parameter list!
```

Comment: Of course, this doesn't solve the `using macros` problem. Try having two `DEF_ATTRIBUTE`s in a class!

Answer (score 3):

The pointer types are not equivalent: A `type_name_t` is a function pointer (a pointer to a free function), whereas `&Test::type_name` is a pointer to member function. This is what the compiler is telling you.

The reason you can't convert a pointer to member function to a simple function pointer is that a (non-static) member function has a hidden `this` parameter. You can't call a member function through a plain function pointer since there would be no way to pass the `this` parameter. You're trying to account for this by giving your `type_name_t` a `CLASS_NAME*` parameter -- conceptually the right thing to do, but C++ doesn't work that way.

Instead, what you need to do is to delare `type_name_t` as a pointer to member function:

```
typedef void (CLASS_NAME::*type_name_t)();
```

(Untested. I hope the syntax is right; I don't use pointers to member functions on a daily basis.)

Comment: How should I change `type_name_t` to match `&Test::type_name`?

Comment: `void (Test::*type_name_t)(Test*)` although I'm pretty sure that this isn't what you want to do. My guess is that you want to change the `type_name()` method into a static method.

Comment: @nakiya: Edited answer to show how the declaration of `type_name_t` should be changed.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: You are right. If the stupid function-pointer to void* cast was available, I would have been home easily though.

Comment: @nakiya Well, such cast of course is possible, the problem is that function pointers can have different size then member pointers and those can have different size then void pointers. Not to mention that your code would break horribly if you would mix member pointers with function pointers.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be : I am just trying to force the linker to export a symbol I can catch later. I am not going to actually call any of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

The types are different.

`&Test::type_name` is a pointer to member function of class `Test` whereas `type_name_t` cannot hold the address of any member function of class `Test`. Its just a pointer to a free function (not to a member function).

Try this:

```
#define CLASS_NAME Test
#define DEF_ATTRIBUTE(type, name) type name;\
    typedef void (CLASS_NAME::*type_name_t)();\
    type_name_t ptr_type_name;\
    void type_name(){( ptr_type_name = &CLASS_NAME::type_name);}\
```